# Solar cell outputting voltage but 0 current

Tags: solar-cell

I recently acquired some small solar cells. When I go to measure the voltage, I get a clear reading, between 190 - 300 mV but hen I try measure the amperage, I get 0 amps, even with the multimeter set to 20 microamps sensitivity. Is the same method done to measure the voltage as it is the amperage on a solar cell (negative lead on the top conducting track and positive on the back).

I got the solar cells from a professor, they should be in working order. The multimeter is set to read dc amps.

Pic is the cells [image: Solar cell]

Comment: Aare you sure you are measuring it correctly? How are you measuring it? With a multimeter or what?

Comment: With a multimeter, Negative lead on the 'blue' side with on the conducting tracks, red lead on the back side.

Comment: Don't forget that multimeters usually use a different input for measuring current and the fuse may have blown in the meter. In general you should NOT use a meter on the current range to measure a voltage source - solar cells are an exception.

Comment: Are these new, known-good cells?  Click the edit link below the question to add where these came from, with a link to information if possible, thanks.

Comment: Yes, but how and with what settings? Is multimeter set to DC or AC current? Is the probe in correct socket for current measurement? Is the multimeter current measurement fuse checked to be OK or blown up?

Comment: All updated, thanks for giving feedback, these posts will be more informative in future.

Comment: @KevinWhite, Solar cells aren't an _exception_ to the don't-connect-an-ammeter-directly-to-a-voltage-source rule. The rule simply does not apply; A PV cell is not a voltage source. It behaves _somewhat_ like a voltage source for current less than some threshold, but if the load tries to draw more current than that, the cell starts to behave more like a current source. https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Solar-Cell-Model-using-single-diode-along-with-series-and-shunt-resistances_fig1_319182103

Comment: Re, "...blown fuse..." If those cells are as big as they look, they may be capable of sourcing several amperes in full sunlight. More than enough to blow the fuse in many multimeters. FYI, the fuse only affects the current scales. Voltage, resistance, and whatever other scales all will continue to work after the fuse has blown. If your meter has a 10A scale (and most likely, a special jack to plug in the + probe for the 10A scale), that's where you should have started.

Comment: @SolomonSlow - precisely. They're an exception in that since they are current limited they don't need to be treated as a voltage source.

Comment: Blown fuse seems to be the case. Thank you all for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would measure them as they are photovoltaic devices is connect them to a resistor. Start with maybe 1K, I have no idea how big they are. Then connect your voltmeter across the resistor and measure the voltage. You can experiment with a few different resistors until you get there rated voltage. Then using ohm's law you can easily calculate the current.